# Adding numbers to a year

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to create a list with the current year and the 4 consecutive:

- 2014
- 2015
- 2016
- 2017
- 2018

This is my approach:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
   echo date("Y") + i);
}
```

This produces:

```
2014201420142014
```

Annother approach:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
   echo (date("Y", strtotime('+' . i . ' years')));
}
```

Gives me:

```
1970197019701970
```

Comment: Are you outputting the data as HTML or raw text in a terminal or document?

Comment: `i` should be `$i`.... if you had errors enabled, you'd see a warning about `undefined constant`, and then `i` is treated as a literal string

Comment: `echo date("Y") + i);` would produce syntax errors, nothing else... "What" is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `i` to `$i`

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
   echo date("Y") + $i . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Also added a `PHP_EOL` so all years appear on separate lines

You can see a working example of it [Here](http://codepad.org/3yX0GBEf)

Comment: This answer will only return 3 additional dates from the current.

Comment: Changed `< 4` to `<= 4` :)

Comment: Uh, no @GeorgeCummins it is not. Without <= (it was previously <) it would only return 3 additional dates.

... and he deleted his comment.

Also it is better to not continue to call date if you are passing the same argument to it. Store it in a variable and then increment each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are

```
    $date = date('Y');
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
       echo $date + $i;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$currentYear = (int) date("Y");
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
   echo ($currentYear + $i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Simplest solution. +1

Comment: `$i <= 4` and `(int)` is not needed - addition of the integer will cast year to integer automatically.

Comment: Needs to be `$i <= 4` to include 2018. Otherwise it stops at 2017

Comment: I didn't check the loop credentials :) I just made year dynamic
Are you surre is automatically converted to INT as I know date() function return STRING type

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to create a list with the current year and the 4 consecutive,
this is how to do it :

```
$currentDate = date("Y");
echo '<ul>';
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    echo 
        '<li>'. ($currentDate + $i) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Again, no need to continuously call date() with the same arguments. Store it in a variable.

Comment: it still works perfectly even if you dont store it a a variable.. i tested it.

Comment: Of course it will work, but why are you using additional resources to call a function 4 times when you know the result will be the same? Cache the result...

Comment: ok il edit it for you.=)